# Excel VBA, to move cells to new columns

Tags: vba, excel

I got an Excel file that looks like this one:

[image: http://screencast.com/t/tpbSFZGjGw]

I want to make a VBA code that moves every 31-th to 60-th row next to the first. Which means that rows from 1 to 30 should stay, rows 31 to 60 should be moved rows 61 to 90 should stay then again 91 to 120 should be moved and so on.

So the final result should be this:

[image: http://screencast.com/t/631F3P492]

I tried making it on my own but it is a problem that I already got something in the rows and I don't know how to make it.

```
Public Sub s()
    Dim position As Long
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim updater As Long

    updater = 30
    position = updater

    For counter = updater + 1 To Rows.Count

    Next counter

    If counter <= position + updater Then
        Cells(i, 1).Font.Color = vbRed
    Else
        position = position + updater
    End If
End Sub
```

I am displaying it with changing its color, but don't know how to make it move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always remember that you can record your actions in excel and than recreate recorded marko to suit your needs. This is perferct example of macro that can be done in such a way and used as learning exersise.

I think you started nice by using "For", but in my opinion row 30 was not best starting point as you want to move every next turn by 30 rows to get to next section of cells. It's preety simple code so I've prepared working macro for you so you could try it out and learn form it:

```
Public Sub create_second_column()
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim starting_cell As Integer
    Dim seleceted_space As Integer
    Dim go_back As Integer

    starting_cell = 1
    seleceted_space = 29
    go_back = 30

    For counter = starting_cell To Rows.Count

        counter = counter + 30

        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(counter, 1), Cells(counter + seleceted_space, 2)).Copy
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(counter - go_back, 4), Cells(counter - go_back, 4)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(counter, 1), Cells(counter + seleceted_space, 2)).ClearContents
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(counter, 1), Cells(counter + seleceted_space, 2)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        ActiveSheet.Rows(counter).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    Next counter

End Sub
```

Comment: Lol, that works pretty well, thank you a lot.

The only thing i would like to change is:

counter = counter + 30

to counter = counter + go_back

Comment: Right :), you've spotted well!